# English Draughts

Tags: c#, game, user-interface, uwp, checkers-draughts

[image: Checkers]

The basic UI for my checkers app is complete, so the next step is to come here for review.  I have not built my Facade over my F# game library, so some of the type usages are a little strange; this will be done as soon as I get the library in a slightly more stable state.

**MainPage.xaml**

This is the opening view (and only view) of my app; it does not have any code-behind:

```xml
<Page
    x:Class="CheckersUI.MainPage"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:local="using:CheckersUI"
    xmlns:custom="using:CheckersUI.CustomControls"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    mc:Ignorable="d">

    <Grid Background="{ThemeResource ApplicationPageBackgroundThemeBrush}">
        <StackPanel>
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Status}"
                       HorizontalAlignment="Center"
                       Margin="0,10"
                       FontWeight="Black"
                       FontSize="20" />
            <Border Height="641"
                    Width="641"
                    BorderThickness="1"
                    BorderBrush="Black">
                <custom:EightPieceBoard Board="{Binding GameController.Board, Mode=OneWay}"
                                        Selection="{Binding Selection, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" />
            </Border>
        </StackPanel>
    </Grid>
</Page>
```

**MainPageViewModel.cs** is the VM for `MainPage`:

```cs
public class MainPageViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private MainPage _page;

    public MainPageViewModel(MainPage page)
    {
        _page = page;
        GameController = new GameController.GameController(Board.defaultBoard, Types.Player.Black);
    }

    private string PlayerToString(Types.Player player) =>
        player.IsWhite ? nameof(Types.Player.White) : nameof(Types.Player.Black);

    private GameController.GameController _gameController;
    public GameController.GameController GameController
    {
        get
        {
            return _gameController;
        }
        set
        {
            _gameController = value;
            OnPropertyChanged();
            OnPropertyChanged(nameof(Status));

        }
    }

    private Types.Coord _selection;
    public Types.Coord Selection
    {
        get
        {
            return _selection;
        }
        set
        {
            if (_selection == null)
            {
                _selection = value;
            }
            else if (_selection != null && PublicAPI.isValidMove(_selection, value, GameController))
            {
                GameController = PublicAPI.move(_selection, value, GameController).Value;
                _selection = null;
            }
            else if (GameController.Board[value.Row][value.Column] == FSharpOption<Piece.Piece>.None)
            {
                _selection = null;
            }
            else
            {
                _selection = value;
            }
        }
    }

    public string Status
    {
        get
        {
            var winningPlayer = PublicAPI.isWon(GameController);
            return FSharpOption<Types.Player>.get_IsSome(winningPlayer)
                   ? $"{PlayerToString(winningPlayer.Value)} Won!"
                   : $"{PlayerToString(GameController.Player)}'s turn";
        }
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null) =>
        PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
}
```

**EightPieceBoard.xaml**

To make managing the board simple, I created a custom UserControl for it.  I gave it this name because it can be reused for any board with 8 pieces per side, and not all checkers variants use boards with 8 pieces per side. Note that I cannot use `UniformGrid` because this is a UWP project.

```xml
<UserControl
    x:Class="CheckersUI.CustomControls.EightPieceBoard"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:local="using:CheckersUI.CustomControls"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    mc:Ignorable="d">

    <Grid>
        <Grid Name="BoardGrid"
              Width="640"
              Height="640"
              PointerPressed="BoardGrid_PointerPressed">
            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <RowDefinition />
                <RowDefinition />
                <RowDefinition />
                <RowDefinition />
                <RowDefinition />
                <RowDefinition />
                <RowDefinition />
                <RowDefinition />
            </Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <ColumnDefinition />
                <ColumnDefinition />
                <ColumnDefinition />
                <ColumnDefinition />
                <ColumnDefinition />
                <ColumnDefinition />
                <ColumnDefinition />
                <ColumnDefinition />
            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <Image Name="BoardImage"
                   Source="../Assets/Checkerboard.png"
                   Grid.RowSpan="8"
                   Grid.ColumnSpan="8" />
        </Grid>
    </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

**EightPieceBoard.xaml.cs**

This is the code-behind for the view discussed above.  One note about this: I am perfectly aware that when I remove pieces, I only remove those that do not exist on the new board, and when I add pieces, I add one for each tile remaining.  This will lead to stacked images, but I did it like this because removing all the tiles caused a nasty flicker, only adding those that did not already exist would have required searching the children list for each piece and checking the grid row and column of each.

```cs
public sealed partial class EightPieceBoard : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private static Dictionary<Piece.Piece, Uri> PieceToUriMap = new Dictionary<Piece.Piece, Uri>
        {
            {Piece.whiteChecker.Value, new Uri("ms-appx:///../Assets/WhiteChecker.png", UriKind.Absolute)},
            {Piece.whiteKing.Value, new Uri("ms-appx:///../Assets/WhiteKing.png", UriKind.Absolute)},
            {Piece.blackChecker.Value, new Uri("ms-appx:///../Assets/BlackChecker.png", UriKind.Absolute)},
            {Piece.blackKing.Value, new Uri("ms-appx:///../Assets/BlackKing.png", UriKind.Absolute)}
        };

    public static readonly DependencyProperty BoardProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register(nameof(Board),
            typeof(IEnumerable<IEnumerable<FSharpOption<Piece.Piece>>>),
            typeof(EightPieceBoard),
            new PropertyMetadata(null, new PropertyChangedCallback((sender, e) => ((EightPieceBoard)sender).LoadPieces())));

    public static readonly DependencyProperty SelectionProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register(nameof(Selection), typeof(Types.Coord), typeof(EightPieceBoard), null);

    public EightPieceBoard()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    public IEnumerable<IEnumerable<FSharpOption<Piece.Piece>>> Board
    {
        get { return (IEnumerable<IEnumerable<FSharpOption<Piece.Piece>>>)GetValue(BoardProperty); }
        set { SetValue(BoardProperty, value); }
    }

    public Types.Coord Selection
    {
        get { return (Types.Coord)GetValue(SelectionProperty); }
        set { SetValue(SelectionProperty, value); }
    }

    private void BoardGrid_PointerPressed(object sender, PointerRoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        var point = e.GetCurrentPoint((Grid)sender).Position;

        var row = (int)Math.Floor(point.Y / 80);
        var column = (int)Math.Floor(point.X / 80);

        Selection = new Types.Coord(row, column);
    }

    private void ClearPieces(IEnumerable<IEnumerable<FSharpOption<Piece.Piece>>> board)
    {
        foreach (Image element in BoardGrid.Children.ToList())
        {
            if (element != BoardImage)
            {
                var row = Grid.GetRow(element);
                var column = Grid.GetColumn(element);
                var uri = ((BitmapImage)element.Source).UriSource.AbsolutePath;

                if (Board.ElementAt(row).ElementAt(column) == FSharpOption<Piece.Piece>.None || PieceToUriMap[Board.ElementAt(row).ElementAt(column).Value].AbsolutePath != uri)
                {
                    BoardGrid.Children.Remove(element);
                }
            }
        }
    }

    private void PlaceChecker(Piece.Piece piece, int row, int column)
    {
        var bitmapImage = new BitmapImage();
        bitmapImage.UriSource = PieceToUriMap[piece];

        var image = new Image();
        image.Source = bitmapImage;
        Grid.SetRow(image, row);
        Grid.SetColumn(image, column);
        BoardGrid.Children.Add(image);
    }

    public void LoadPieces()
    {
        ClearPieces(Board);

        for (var rowIndex = 0; rowIndex < Board.Count(); rowIndex++)
        {
            for (var colIndex = 0; colIndex < Board.ElementAt(rowIndex).Count(); colIndex++)
            {
                var piece = Board.ElementAt(rowIndex).ElementAt(colIndex);
                if (piece == FSharpOption<Piece.Piece>.None)
                {
                    continue;
                }

                PlaceChecker(piece.Value, rowIndex, colIndex);
            }
        }
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    private void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null) =>
        PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
}
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

A couple of things:

```
<Grid Background="{ThemeResource ApplicationPageBackgroundThemeBrush}">
    <StackPanel>
        ...
```

Putting the `StackPanel` as single child of the grid is wasteful.
Add `RowDefinitions` to the grid. As a rule of thumb `StackPanel` is almost never right. After writing WPF for a couple of years you will probably find yourself using `Grid` ~95% of the time. Grid is a bit verbose but it is the panel you will not have to refactor away from. Also Grid makes reasoning about layout simpler. You can try [this](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Gu.Wpf.GridExtensions/) to bring down the verbosity a bit.

You can add [BindsTwoWayByDefault](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.frameworkpropertymetadata.bindstwowaybydefault(v=vs.110).aspx) to EightPieceBoard.Selection but I don't mind being expliclit about it.

The viewmodel should not know about the view: `public MainPageViewModel(MainPage page)` it makes testing harder and is smelly in general. Not a clean separation of responsibilites between view & viewmodel.

```
<Grid>
    <Grid Name="BoardGrid"
```

Same as above, don't add the grid as single child to the outer grid. This can hurts performance and is noisy to read. Better with a grid than a stackpanel though :)

Answer (score 4):

I've spotted...

> ```
> private string PlayerToString(Types.Player player) =>
>     player.IsWhite ? nameof(Types.Player.White) : nameof(Types.Player.Black);
> ```

I find the `Player` should have a property that is one of the two enum values

```
enum PlayerColor
{
    Black,
    White,
}
```

With this you don't need the `IsWhite` boolean and the conversion method because you can either use `.ToString()` on it or in many cases it will be implicitly converted.

---

> ```
> Piece.Piece
> ```

This is a code smell. The class and the namespace shouldn't have the same names.

The namespace should probably by `Pieces`.

---

> ```
>        OnPropertyChanged();
>        OnPropertyChanged(nameof(Status));
> ```

You should not need the second call to `OnPropertyChanged`. Without parameters it should already trigger an update to all properties.

---

> ```
> private void ClearPieces(IEnumerable<IEnumerable<FSharpOption<Piece.Piece>>> board)
> ```

This method requires a parameter but you don't seem to use it anywhere.

Comment: `Player` is a discriminated union from F#.  `Piece` is a `Piece` type in the `Piece` module in F#.  The first call only updates the `GameController` property--it takes the method name from the caller automatically.  You are correct about the last point.

Comment: Points 1 and 2 will be fixed once I get the Facade up.

Comment: I would offer that `nameof(Types.Player.x)` is an extremely convoluted and fragile way of writing `"x"`. Coupling the user-visible display name `"White"` to the *internal program identifier* `Types.Player.White` makes it very hard to change either one (e.g. to `"Blanco"` or `WHITE` respectively). Write clearly and simply what you mean: don't succumb to "enterprise programmer envy."